# Quadratic program with matrix decision variable

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have a quadratic optimization program with a vector and matrix decision variable. It is of the form

\begin{align}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \delta Q \in \mathbb{S}^n} & \frac{1}{2}x^T (Q + \delta Q)^T (Q + \delta Q) x - e^T x\\
\text{ subject to }& x_i \geq 0, \quad 1 \leq i \leq n,\\
&-r \leq \delta Q_{(i,j)} \leq r,\quad  1\leq i,j \leq n,
\end{align}

where $r \geq 0$ and $Q \in \mathbb{S}^n$ are constants and $e$ is the vector of ones.

Is there any way I can solve this as an SDP or with an SDP solver?

Answer (score 2):

No, this function is nonconvex, which you can see rather easily by restricting to some sub-space and specific data, for instance $Q=1$ and along the ray $x = t, \delta Q = -2t$.

Comment: Sorry I did not type up the complete question. I've edited it above